# Laravel get array of values imploded from Form Request

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-8, laravel-formrequest

I have the following rules in my From Request:

```
return [
    'brand_id' => 'required|numeric',
    'name' => 'required|string',
    'wage_type_id' => 'required|numeric',
    'work_days' => 'required|array',
    'weekly_min' => 'required|numeric',
    'weekly_max' => 'required|numeric',
    'weekly_utmost' => 'required|numeric',
    'daily_std' => 'required|numeric',
    'daily_min' => 'required|numeric',
    'daily_max' => 'required|numeric',
];
```

One of them, work_days is supposed to be sent as an array.

I could create the work type from validated form request like

```
WorkType::create($request->all());
```

BUT I cannot store an array in database for sure.

**Is there a way to get work_days imploded** so that I can use the one line above to create my record from the request directly?

Note: I want the array imploded, not json encoded, because I'm going to insert into a field type of SET.

Comment: Accept the array and encode it as a `json` ?

Comment: [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode), [serialize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize)

Comment: @Tithira How to do it in the form request?

Comment: @JustCarty How can I apply them in rules?

Comment: I am assuming that you have formatted the code according to [Laravel documentation for validation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic), if so, you can process data by using [this method](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#inserts) after a successful validation aforementioned. You can store by using `'work_days' => json_encode($request->work_days),` in the create method without storing them directly via `WorkType::create($request->all());`

Comment: @Tithira Thank you, I know that I can do like that, I am looking for an extra feature here (if there is), besides I want them imploded, not json encoded.

Comment: You want the Request to implode for you? That's not a clever idea. It will just add a layer of confusion to any new developer, just so that you can call $request->all() rather than getting each property separately. I'd actually prefer to get each property separately as it means that there will be no undesired behaviour later down the line.

Comment: @JustCarty Well, Laravel has many features, so I thought why not a way for this? I checked all the rules but couldn't find. So it seems I have to do like that, get each property separately and implode the array myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually modify the request params before creating the model in your controller.

```
$request->merge([
    "work_days" => implode(", ", $request->work_days)
]);

WorkType::create($request->all());
```

If you want it to be in the `FormRequest`, override the `passedValidation()` method

```
class SampleFormRequest extends FormRequest
{

    public function passedValidation()
    {
        $this->request->add([
            "work_days" => implode(", ", $this->request->get("work_days"))
        ]);
    }
}
```

But for me, I prefer writing all properties separately and not using the `$request->all()`